# Data not showing up if dates are null?

Tags: datatables

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr12qd21/)

When any of the Dates are null, none of the data shows up.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
              function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

                  var today = new Date();
                  var dd = today.getDate();
                  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
                  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                  if (dd < 10)
                      dd = '0' + dd;

                  if (mm < 10)
                      mm = '0' + mm;

                  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

                  if ($('#min').val() !== '' || $('#max').val() !== '') {
                      var iMin_temp = $('#min').val();
                      if (iMin_temp === '') {
                          iMin_temp = '01/01/2009';
                      }

                      var iMax_temp = $('#max').val();
                      if (iMax_temp === '') {
                          iMax_temp = '01/03/2012';
                      }

                      var arr_min = iMin_temp.split("/");
                      var arr_max = iMax_temp.split("/");
                      var arr_date = aData[4].split("/");

                      var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
                      var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
                      var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

                      if (iMin === "" && iMax === "") {
                          return true;
                      }
                      else if (iMin === "" && iDate < iMax) {
                          return true;
                      }
                      else if (iMin <= iDate && "" === iMax) {
                          return true;
                      }
                      else if (iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax) {
                          return true;
                      }
                      return false;
                  }
              }
          );

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    var data = [
        ["Capture IronMan", null],
        ["Capture Captain America", "12/12/2015"],
        ["Capture Sentry", "1/1/2001"],
        ["Capture Hulk", "2/2/2012"],
        ["Capture Nightcrawler", null],
    ]


    var table = $('#activeProjects').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "data": data,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "mRender": function(data) {
                    return '<a href="ExistingProject?jobNumber=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ],

        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

    });

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        location.reload();
    });

    $('#min, #max').keyup(function () {
        table.api().draw();
    });

    $('#mindate').change( function() { table.api().draw(); } );
    $('#maxdate').change( function() { table.api().draw(); } );


});

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table display" id="activeProjects">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th><span style="white-space: nowrap;">From: <input type="text" id="mindate" name="mindate" class="form-control numberFilter datepicker" /> To: <input class="form-control numberFilter datepicker" type="text" id="maxdate" name="maxdate" /></span></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Completion Date</th>
           </tr>


        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Completion Date</th>
            </tr>

        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="clear">Clear Filters</button>
</div>

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */


/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -40px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {

    height: 40px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}


.numberFilter {
    width: 75px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I have lots of null dates in the data for incomplete projects. How do I force the table to load the data even when the dates are null?

**Note**
The page loads and works fine without the date filter, but I need the date filter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You can add this line as the first line in your filtering function to always show entries with invalid date.

```js
// Show entries with no valid date with no filtering applied
if(!/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/.test(aData[1])){ return true; }
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr12qd21/3/) for code and demonstration.

**NOTES**

You may need to re-think on how you do the filtering. You're re-filtering on `change` event which is only triggered when user leaves the input. That seems very confusing. Also you're not performing date validation in your filtering function.

Maybe you should use date picker similar to how [yadcf plug-in](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) does it or even [yadcf plug-in](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) altogether..

Comment: I have not been able to get yadcf to work. Whenever I try and use it, I get console errors in the yadcf source